# Set TabularView to false programatically

Tags: 2010, development, web-part

I am working in a custom web part for a customer and part of what i need to accomplish is creating a view for a list that i am also creating. Everything is fine until the point i want to set TablularView for that view to false. 
I thought it as as simple as:

```
SPView view = new SPView(newList, xml);
newList.Views.Add(view.Title, view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection(), view.Query, view.RowLimit, view.Paged, true);
newList.Views[view.Title].SetViewXml(schema);
newList.Views[view.Title].TabularView = false;
newList.Views[view.Title].Update();
```

But after debugging this part of the code TabularView stays TRUE, any hints?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best answer but I found a workaround for this. Hope this helps someone. If someone knows a better way to do it please post it:

```
SPView view = new SPView(newList, xml);
newList.Views.Add(view.Title, view.ViewFields.ToStringCollection(), view.Query, view.RowLimit, view.Paged, true);

SPView newView = newList.Views[view.Title];
newView.TabularView = false;
newView.Update();
```